# Qt linguist why I cant alter the default translation

Tags: qt, linguistics

I tried to open one of the default ts files from the linguist tool and figured that I am not able to edit the translations, If I have installed the binaries.but then I am able to do it if I have built the source my self. Could some one explain why this is ?

Comment: Stupid question: couldn't that be a file permissions issue? Installed Qt's directory shouldn't be writeable by default, while compiled one yes. Try copying .ts files from Qt's directory to somewhere writeable.

Comment: Thank you my dear friends for the comment. I definitely check if the file translations is Read only and it is not. If one has really come across this they would realize that those components are displayed in light gray and can not edit once the file is open with linguist program. I am true happy about your question and only because of that I realize that I have not given all the details required.